# Layout problems with table in IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, layout

Please check [this link](http://www.ncbmwmotorcycles.com/bmw-specials/) Please browse it using Chrome then compare it to IE. Correct layout should look like ones in Chrome. As you see in "Action" column, How do I fix it?

Chrome view:

[image]

IE view:

[image]

Comment: I read the title of this and was like "Of course your having trouble with IE" - Then I chuckled.

Comment: Yeah, apparently, I need to fix it

Comment: It has to do with your `class="mobile-none"` What is that class supposed to do anyways? I see it either `display: block` or it `display: none` but I removed it and didn't really notice a difference either way...

Comment: the display: none is for mobile view. the 4th column shouldn't be visible

Comment: Uh, I don't... see the issue? http://prntscr.com/czw491 I'm using Win10, though. Maybe just remove whatever is producing that grey border?